# Unable To Enable Bluetooth on a Dell N4110

Tags: 11.10, bluetooth

I'm using Ubuntu 11.10. When I turn on Bluetooth and go into 'Preferences' I am unable to move the slider to 'On'.

It just slides back to off. Screenshot:

[image]

I installed Blueman Bluetooth Manager from the Software Center but it didn't work at all.

Can anyone tell me how can I enable it? Need to transfer files from my Samsung phone.

Comment: Do you have a button on your keyboard to activate or deactivate bluetooth, or a hardware switch? This may be blocking bluetooth from turning on. Which model of PC/laptop are you using?

Comment: I am using Dell Inspiron N4110. The hardware switch is on. If you see the screenshot, the bluetooth icon is bright, indicating that it is 'On'. It's just I am unable to move the slider and enable it.

Answer (score 5):

OP solved this problem by upgrading to 12.04:

> Thanks for the help Will. But I upgraded to 12.04 and it worked! May be it was some glitch with 11.10.

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same problem with a Vaio VPC-SB35SB/B.
The bluetooth works only when I first start windows and then reboot and start ubuntu. But if I shutdown completely, when I power on the notebook again, the bluetooth is disabled.

I tried to solve it for many ways, doing the command below:

```
sudo hciconfig hci0 up
```

When I executed this command, it returns me a timeout and nothing happens. I thought that this should be a problem with the session and I've tried to add this command to run at startup, but it doesn't works too.

I got this problem today with the wireless. I shutdown my wireless switching the button on my note. When I tried to turn on again, the wireless was not working. I solved this running this command:

```
sudo rfkill unblock all
```

And my wireless switched on again.

Try the last command with the bluetooth, because now my bluetooth is working. When it stop to work, I will try it. If you have any progress, please tell me.

Sorry for my english. It's not my native language.

Comment: Thanks for the help Will. But I upgraded to 12.04 and it worked! May be it was some glitch with 11.10.